# Textfield clears after calendar control postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have 3 text fields on my page and one calendar control. After I fill in the 3 text boxes, then click a date on the calendar control, the bottom textfield clears out, losing its value. The other 2 text boxes have their values available and do not get cleared. The textboxes all have the same properties, but I can't figure out how to keep the value in the third textbox.

```
    <table class="auto-style2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right">Project Name:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtProjectName" runat="server" height="32px" width="211px" MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="TxtProjectName_TextChanged" onKeyUp="Count(this,50)" onChange="Count(this,50)" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtProjectName" ErrorMessage="Field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<table class="auto-style2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right">Project Description:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDescription" runat="server" height="45px" width="211px" TextMode="MultiLine" OnTextChanged="TxtDescription_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtDescription" ErrorMessage="Field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right">Contact Name:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtContactName" runat="server" Width="203px" OnTextChanged="TxtContactName_TextChanged" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtContactName" ErrorMessage="Field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style5">Business Area:</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLBusinessArea" runat="server" style="text-align: left">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right">Priority:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPriority" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right">Desired Completion Date:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server">
                <SelectedDayStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                <TodayDayStyle ForeColor="#3333FF" />
            </asp:Calendar>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Its the TxtContactName that clears.

Comment: you do not need to show so much mark up code only that part that pertains to the issue at hand.. also are you familiar with `IsPostBack` and `__DoPostBack()` method..? you will need some javascript to capture the event data..

Comment: Maybe you reset it on code behind

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` method in the code behind and check if the text box has got it's value there. If it's there, this means it may be cleared in code behind, as suggested in another comment.

Comment: I don't find any reason for Textbox to clear. Post some code of calendar event handler.

Comment: When I put it in load it is an empty string, but tracing through the debugger doesn't have that textbox being touvhed

Comment: There is no code behind for the calendar

Comment: As soon as the calendar date is changed it empties out the value if the textbox. even if there's a value in the box visually, it shows an empty string upon date change